# How to create a list with checkboxes in Automator?

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

How difficult is it to create in Automator (either AppleScript or Javascript) something like this?

[image]

I would like to have a groceries list.

And only the selected items to be copied in clipboard line by line so I can paste them in my list in notes.

Comment: Why not just use **Notes**, which has a _checklist format_, for your groceries list?

Answer (score 1):

## Not with Automator

This is not possible using only Automator and an Open Scripting Architecture (OSA) language. Automator is not intended to present arbitrary user interfaces.

### Alternatives

An alternative approach would be to create an Objective-C/AppleScript application, or a local web page and JavaScript.

There appear to be third party tools, such as [Dialog Maker](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/dialog-maker/id457389999?mt=12), that may help.